# Intertemporal choice with no income flow in the second period

Tags: microeconomics, utility

Question:

> Suppose Mr X maximises his utility for two periods, his total utility is given by  log $c_1$ + $\beta$ log $c_2$ where $\beta$ $\in$ ( 0,1) and $c_1$ and $c_2$ are his consumption for period 1 and period 2 respectively. Suppose he earns a wage only in period 1 and it is given by W. He saves for the second period on which he enjoys a gross return of (1+r) where r > 0 is the net interest rate. Suppose the government implements a scheme where T $\geq$ 0 is collected from agents ( this is also from Mr. X) in the first period and returns the same amount T back in the second period. What is the optimum T for which his total utility is maximised?.

My working: I tried putting $c_2= [(M -  c_1- T ) ( 1 + r )] + T$ and plugged in the values that helps the consumer achieve optimum utility for the given budget constraint. Using the lagrangean method of optimisation I got the following 
$$\frac{c_2}{\beta c_1} = 1+r$$ 
Solving the budget constraint using this, I got $$ c_2=\frac{\beta[ M ( 1 + r) - Tr ]}{\beta+ 1}$$Next I tried differentiating $c_2$ with respect to T so as to find the optimum T that maximises $c_2$ and in turn the utility function. This method doesn't seem to work. Could somebody correct me ?. Thank you.

Comment: Just build a budget constraint instead

Comment: 123, isn't the budget constraint just the same as the equation for second period consumption with all terms exception M (1 + r ) swapped to the left, what difference would that make ?

Comment: "tried maximising the budget constraint" How does one maximize a constraint...?

Comment: Can you show in detail which the calculation, including the optimal c1 and c2?

Comment: luchonacho I've added edits to my question, could you refer to that now. Also sorry for the very late reply.

Comment: denesp, I'm sorry that was a huge error in my wording. I've edited the question and included my working now. Can I know why my question was closed off topic as well ?

Comment: The question you are trying to answer seems weird to me. Suppose we take $T>0$ from X in period 1 but give him an extra $T$ to spend in period 2. I can't see how that can ever be better than taking zero from him in period 1. Worst case scenario is that X saves *all* of the extra $T$ we left him in period 1, giving him $T(1+r)$ to spend in period 2 (which is clearly better than having only $T$ to spend). But if X chooses not to save all of the extra $T$ then it must be because there is some other consumption plan that does even better still.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ubiquitous, so the answer should be T = 0, it matches with the answer key that was provided. Thanks once again!